# Chrome DNS fetch holding onto old dns information

Tags: google-chrome

I have recently updated cname records for a domain. The dns change has taken affect on other browsers and has taken affect on chrome when using a profile that has never been to the site before. However for my main browser, chrome (macos 10.8, chrome v25), is holding onto the old dns and has not updated.

I have read of fixes that involve clearing cache etc, but my concern is that if it is happening to me, it would also be happening to users of the site.

So my question is, how long will Chrome continue to store the old DNS settings? is there a way to force chrome to refresh its DNS in a way that would make it simple for general users?

Answer (score -2):

Type **chrome://net-internals/#dns** in address bar of chrome browser.

Click "Clear host cache" button

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc3dM.png)